# Why is Capybara not matching new DOM elements inserted after an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm using Rails 5, and Capybara. I created a simple Rails view search form. Upon submit, vanilla JS takes over with preventDefault and performs AJAX to get search results. The results are then packaged into a table, and appended to the DOM. The page works fine in development, however, capybara is not cooperating in my feature specs:

`expected to find css "#search_results table" but there were no matches`.

Just as a sanity check, I matched css that was already present in my view, so Capybara can do some matching correctly, just not the JS-introduced elements.

I've set some standard Ruby `sleep x`, and `wait: x` in the Capybara matchers. Also have seen some articles with examples of custom methods to force Capybara to wait, but those require jquery which I am not using. I expect capybara to handle this vanilla JS, but have had no luck getting it to work here. Please help.

View:

```
<div id='media_search'>
  <%= form_for(:search, method: "get", html: {class: "navbar-form navbar-left form-inline"}) do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :search %>
   <%= f.text_field :search, id: "media_search_field", class: "form-control", placeholder: "song, album, or artist" %>
   <%= f.submit "Submit", id: "media_search_submit", class: "btn btn-default" %>
  <% end %>

  <div id='search_results'></div>
</div>
```

Snippet of vanilla JS:

```
var ajaxSearchMedia = function (query, successCb) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', '/search?query=' + query, true);

  request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      // Success!
      var songs = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      successCb(songs);
    } else { ...
```

Feature test:

```
scenario "with results" do
  visit '/'

  fill_in "media_search_field", with: "song"

  click_on "media_search_submit"

  expect(page).to have_css("#search_results table")
end
```

Comment: What driver are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scenario statement isn't tagged with `js: true` which, if using the normal capybara configuration, means you're using the default rack-test driver which doesn't support JS.  You will need to configure tests that depend on JS behaviors to use a driver that supports JS - see https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#selecting-the-driver .  You will also need to configure the same tests not to use transactional testing - see https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#transactions-and-database-setup and https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example

Comment: Actually, for Rails 5 transactional feature tests should be possible. If all else fails, use Test Prof's [Active Record Shared Connection](https://test-prof.evilmartians.io/#/active_record_shared_connection.md) backport.

Comment: @Epigene This answer was from 2016 and was true then - Yes, for Rails 5.1+ transactional testing should work fine with  JS tests and database_cleaner should no longer be necessary.   On a related note, while the shared connection hack for Rails 5.0 you've linked to will work most of the time, as your app becomes more complicated it will eventually lead to random deadlocks that are very hard to debug - there is no 100% safe way to do multithreaded transactional testing with Rails < 5.1